# Limit bandwidth of guest wi-fi?

Tags: networking, router, modem, bandwidth

I'm looking for a modem (or a router) or a custom firmware for a modem/router to let me expose to guests a guest wi-fi network with limited bandwidth or with lower priority against the main network.

I want users to be able to connect to such wi-fi, do their stuff, but not affect the navigation of the devices connected to the main network.
It should act as access point for a public place where I have even some computers which must be connected to internet all the time and must have the highest bandwidth possible.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Are the system critical machines on WIfi or Ethernet? If they're wifi you want to use completely separate AP for guest access so that wifi congestion/flooding doesnt impact them, QoS wont fix that. What speed is your WAN connection?

Comment: @Linef4ult They are both on Ethernet and WiFi, the connection is quite slow, I think it's a 5mbit/s.

Comment: At that kinda speeds I wouldnt even bother providing open access. You could link an AP and limit it to maybe 1Mb/0.1Mb US, but that wouldnt be usable. Good QoS needs an experienced tech to setup and significantly more advanced equipment.

Comment: You need a router that supports the **tomato** or **dd-wrt** firmware to engage QOS.